# JQuery event listener call function by name with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen other questions similar to this one, but I cant seem to find the answer i'm looking for.

Is there any way of passing parameters into a named function in a JQuery event listener?

For example, I know I can do this

```
$('#myelement').on("change", function(){
  var value = $(this).val();   
  myFunction(value);
});
```

But is there any way to just pass the function name into the event listener instead?

Something like this

```
$('#myelement').on("change", myFunction($(this).val()));
```

I thought it would be straight forward to be honest, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: If it was a static value, yes, but since value changes, not really.

Comment: Not possible to use `$(this)` as an argument this way. It does not refer to your event (refers to higher namespace).

Comment: You can pass function name but can't pass the value like that but I don't see the need of it because you can just get the value inside of the `myFunction`

Comment: Why is this a problem? Just do it the right way. The way that works. The second argument to `.on` should be a function. The way you're trying to do it, the argument would be the return value of the function instead. And the function would be called once, instead of every time a `'change'` event was fired. If you don't like the syntax, you could do `var handleChange = function() { var value = $(this).val(); myFunction(value); }; $('#myelement').on("change", handleChange);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters to the handler function using jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Its format is `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`, where `data` is any object you need to pass. Later it can be accessed via `event.data` property in the handler.

Check this example. Note that if you just want to access `$(this).val()` then you don't need any parameters: `myFunction` is already bound to the target element, so you can use `$(this).val()` inside of it.

```js
$("#i").on("change", null, "My parameter", myFunction);

function myFunction(event) {
   console.log("Parameter: " + event.data);
   console.log("$(this).val() = " + $(this).val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="i"> Enter something and press Enter
```

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: @S_R I was glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery "[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)" method, then invoke the `click` event listener and last but not least call the function that you created.

```js
$('button').on('click', clicked);

function clicked() {
 var val = $('#one').val();
  $('.response').html('<p>Value is ' + val + '</p>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="one">
<button>Click Me</button>

<p class="response"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand what you want, one workaround I've used is to refer to functions in an array like follows

```js
list_of_functions = [function_1,function_2];

function function_1(){
  alert("function 1 running");
}
function function_2(){
  console.dir("function 2 running");  
}

function run_function(function_index){
  return list_of_functions[function_index]();
}

$("#function_select").on("change",function(){
  run_function(this.value);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="function_select">
  <option disabled selected>Please select a function</option>
  <option value="0">function 1</option>
  <option value="1">function 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I do not think what OP says in the text is what they actually meant.